# Postgersql change the label for a query in case condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-constant

I have a query like this

```
SELECT "source"."User Profile__user_type", case  when "User Profile__user_type" = 4 then cast("User Profile__user_type" as text)="BUILDER" end AS "User Profile__user_type", sum("source"."totalPrice") AS "sum"
FROM (SELECT "public"."master_order"."id" AS "id","public"."master_order"."totalPrice" AS "totalPrice", "public"."master_order"."status" AS "status",   "User Profile"."user_id" AS "User Profile__user_id", "User Profile"."user_type" AS "User Profile__user_type" 
FROM "public"."master_order" FULL JOIN "django_db_schema"."user_profile" "User Profile" ON "public"."master_order"."orderedBy"::uuid = "User Profile"."user_id"
WHERE ("public"."master_order"."status" = 1 OR "public"."master_order"."status" = 8)
LIMIT 1048575) "source"
GROUP BY "source"."User Profile__user_type"
ORDER BY "sum" ASC, "source"."User Profile__user_type" ASC
```

In this query I have "User Profile__user__type" as an int here if its an int of 4 I want the output to have a label as "Builder" but Im getting this error

```
    SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "BUILDER" does not exist
  Position: 130

Error position: line: 1 pos: 129
```

Breaking my head over this since a few days help is appreciated

Comment: So it just checks for the column named "Builder" and it fails to find the value and raises the error

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS